# First order and second order phase transition in signal recovery

Tags: computational-physics, phase-transition

**Warning**: I'm a computer scientist and my understanding about physics is very limited

Recently I came across the term first-order phase transition in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02476) where we try to recover a signal $x$ from $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$. We look at the setting where $\alpha = m/n$ is fixed whereas $n \to \infty$.

They defined a first order phase transition as the region $(\alpha_c, \alpha_s)$ where the recovery is hard but not impossible where $\alpha_c$ is the ratio $m/n$ which is the transition where its information-theoretically possible to recover the signal and $\alpha_c$ is the transition where we can recover the signal efficiently.
[image]

They briefly introduced second order phase transitions and but as far as I can see they didnt explain what it means in this setting.

Since a first order phase transition is defined as a discontinuity in the transition and a second order phase transition as a continuous transition, am I correct to assume that if $a_c = a_s$ we have a second order state transition instead of a first order state transition?